# Transparent Sticky Headers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy

**Tl;dr:** Sticky recycler view headers that are also transparent seem impossible. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking to build out a UI with a similar sticky header effect to the Apple Music app ([example](https://gifyu.com/image/SM8pX)).
Unfortunately this is a hard feature to implement. I have found no one who has done this before in the Android coding community.

#### Things I've tried:

1. Overlay a custom view (header lookalike) and try to keep it in sync with the scroll state of either a recycler view or scroll view
2. Constantly grab a bitmap of the view behind where the sticky part should be and add it to the sticky headers

##### Issues with the above ^

1. Since you need to move the scrolling view up and down depending on the state - this has been unusable given the jittery nature of moving while scrolling
2. This kills most any device since it requires a decent amount of RAM to keep running (plus it just feels gross)

**Lastly...**
I want to make it clear that I'm not looking for a code snippet to save the day. I'm simply looking for some general direction that others may also benefit from. If you've done something like this before - please chime in.

Answer (score 0):

teak a look at this [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) I'm sure you can find your solution there or at lees get some idea of how to solve your problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32142046)